# Добавление объектов в массив с помощью литерала {}

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, корзина

Нужно добавлять элементы в массив при клике на кнопку

Вот мой код:

```
let basket = [];
basket.push({
    name: this.previousSibling.textContent,
    item: this.parentNode.id
});
```

Пробовала прописать basket.push(1), но код похоже заменяет просто всё и пересоздаёт элемент

Comment: Если при нажатии на кнопку срабатывает весь указанный тут код, то не удивительно. У вас первой же строчкой создается массив в который добавляется один объект. При последующем нажатии на кнопку, снова создается новый массив и добавляется первый новый объект. Вам стоит вынести массив вне обработки нажатия на кнопку, в целом это так и должно быть, ведь вы где-то этот массив потом используете?

Comment: Да, я хотела с моими знаниями попробовать сделать что-то вроде интернет-магазина, чтобы опыта набраться. А как мне это исправить?

Comment: Вынести ссылку на массив наружу (вне обработчика нажатия на кнопку). Хорошо бы вообще все в класс обернуть. :)

Comment: Блин, а я ещё классы не изучила.. А как добавлять объект в массив при нажатии на кнопку, если код нужно вынести? Что-то трудно мне даются эти ваши онклики((

Comment: никто не мешает создать массив за пределами функции, которая передается в onclick. Далее внутри этой функции ссылаться на этот массив. Хотел бы ответить подробнее, но я сейчас не с компьютера. =\

Comment: Большое спасибо. Ты направил меня на верное решение <33